# how do i process this file using awk or perl?

Tags: perl, awk

I want to process some log file whose format is like:

```
<itemA>    <num>
<itemB>    <num>
<itemC>    <num>
```

I want to get a summary that contains the following information

for each item I want to know the range of the `<num>` field and the average of `<num>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Seth, and prefer his answer.  Here is a manual solution in Awk, for learning purposes:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#invoke with: < infile stats.awk
{
  i = $1; v = $2;
  count[i]++; 
  sum[i] += v; 
  if (v > max[i] || count[i] == 1) { max[i] = v }; 
  if (v < min[i] || count[i] == 1) { min[i] = v };
} 

END {
  for (i in count) {
    print i " range: " min[i] ".." max[i] " avg: " sum[i] / count[i] 
  }; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
use Statistics::Lite;

while (<>)
{
   my ($a,$b) = split;
   push(@{$items{$a}},$b);
}
foreach my $key (keys %items)
{
  print "$key\n";
  print Statistics::Lite::statsinfo(@{$items{$key}});
}
```

Obviously you could do the statistics manually, but…why bother?

Comment: Thanks for tip on [Statistics::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics::Lite). However there is a typo regarding parens next to `push` statement - should be something like `push @{$items{$a}}, $b;`

Comment: Make that:  `push( @{ $items{$a} }, $b );`